# Not sure how to map object contents to display in app

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to display contents of an object in frontend of my app. The object console logs like the following-

[image]

I want to display 'dashboardTitle' by mapping it over each screens' AppHeader in my app. I have tried to do the following but none of the below will render 'dashboardTitle'.

```
const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([]);

{filtered.map(item => (
  <Text style={styles.headerText}>
    {item.dashboardName} - {item.dashboardTitle}
  </Text>
))}
{filtered.map((item, index)=>(
 <Text style={styles.headerText} key={index}>
   {item.dashboardName}
 </Text>  
))}
{messages.map((message, key)=>(
 <Text style={styles.headerText}>
   {message.dashboardName}
 </Text>  
))}
```

Here is the full AppHeader code-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Keyboard, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';
import { theme } from '../theme';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { apiStateReducer } from '../reducers/ApiStateReducer';
import CognitensorEndpoints from '../services/network/CognitensorEndpoints';
import DefaultView from '../components/default/DefaultView';
import DashboardListCard from '../components/DashboardListCard';
import DashboardHeader from '../components/DashboardHeader';
import DashboardGridCard from '../components/DashboardGridCard';
import {
  NavigationContainer,
  useFocusEffect,
} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const AppHeader = ({
  scene,
  previous,
  navigation,
  searchIconVisible = false,
  item,
  index,
  onPress
}) => {
  const [dashboards, dispatchDashboards] = useReducer(apiStateReducer, {
    data: [],
    isLoading: true,
    isError: false,
  });
  const [gridView, setGridView] = useState(false);

  const toggleGridView = () => {
    setGridView(!gridView);
  };

  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([]);

  const setLoading = () => {
  const messages = dashboards.data.message.filter((item) => {
      const title = item.dashboardTitle || item.dashboardName;
      return title.toLowerCase();
    });
    setFiltered(messages);
    console.log(filtered);
  };

  const dropShadowStyle = styles.dropShadow;
  const toggleSearchVisibility = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Search');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('abcd');
    setLoading();
    CognitensorEndpoints.getDashboardList({
      dispatchReducer: dispatchDashboards,
    });
    CognitensorEndpoints.getList({
      dispatchReducer: dispatchDashboards,
    });
  },[]);

  return (
    <>
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <View style={styles.headerLeftIcon}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigation.pop}>
          {previous ? (
            <MaterialIcons
              name="chevron-left"
              size={24}
              style={styles.visible}
            />
          ) : (
            <MaterialIcons
              name="chevron-left"
              size={24}
              style={styles.invisible}
            />
            )}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      {filtered.map(item => (
      <Text style={styles.headerText}>
        {item.dashboardTitle}
      </Text>
    ))}
      <View style={styles.headerRightIconContainer}>
        {searchIconVisible ? (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styles.headerRightIcon, dropShadowStyle]}
            onPress={toggleSearchVisibility}>
            <MaterialIcons name="search" size={24} style={styles.visible} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : (
          <View style={styles.invisible} />
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  </>
  );
};
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I got it, when are you rendering the headers? I mean, do you want to display a list or do you want to have a dynamic name for each header but you're receiving all the headers' titles once? Maybe if you attach an image, it would be more clear

Comment: Yes header names console log as 'dashboardTitlte' as in the object. I have to dynamically map each title to show as app header on each screen in the app. I figured setLoading is not mounting so I included it within useEffect but that's also returning errors. See above I have edited code to include the setLoading() function. But I think I am not including it correctly, that's why the error.

Comment: Well, in that way, if you don't need to render a list, you should keep somewhere your array of titles and choose which one you're displaying by the name of your screen. The `map` that you've written is generating you a list of titles, but as you said you don't want that. What you could do is to send a prop to your header with an index number (which tells you which screen you're on to) and by that one you should display the header